# Chat Smartsupp-Drupal Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem with the smartsupp chat on drupal,

This is the code to call a chat box which I insert into a php page, but the problem is that it takes a long time to load. How you could optimize the script so that the load is fast.

```
<!-- Smartsupp Live Chat script -->
<script src="js/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = '425fb33bf5e0cf0b359b9e60a17d16a78fd5efa3';
window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='//www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

Comment: Does the first scrip tag also load the smartsupp loader?

Comment: Yes, but also try it this way "www. **. Com / loader.js"

Answer (score 1):

this is Vladimir from Smartsupp.

Do you use visitor recording inside Smartsupp? This feature has the biggest load. If the load time is your primary concern, you can turn visitor recording off (gear icon in visitor recording tab).

Little bit of info about the Smartsupp script load time:

Smartsupp chat script size is 112 KB. Size of all Smartsupp elements when loaded is 450 KB and it takes 230 ms to load on a broadband internet connection. The script is asynchronous so it doesn’t slow down the loading of the website. You can see script load details here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vy54qnuko7884n/_Smartsupp%20script%20load%20time.png?dl=0

If you have further questions, you can contact us at support@smartsupp.com.